# CoreData Relationship Saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am having troubles with the relationship I have setup in CoreData. Its one to many, a table can have many people but only one person can sit at one table.

My app is based off Apples CoreDataBooks example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

This does't handle relationships though. You see the 'EditingViewController.m' in the example project, I have this as well, its where the user edits and saves a change to a chosen attribute of a CoreData object.

So let's say they go and choose to edit the `name` attribute of my person entity. They get a text field where they enter a name and then tap the save button, done.

Now my person entity has a relationship with my table entity, but I can't get it saving correctly and it's likely that I don't fully understand how it works yet. So let's say they select to edit the table of that person, they get a UIPickerView howling a list of tables, great, I've gotten this far, I've used a fetch request to get the table objects and list them.

Normally setting a standard attribute, a line such as this would be called in my code:

`[editedObject setValue:textField.text forKey:editedFieldKey];`

However, this time I am using a relationship so this won't work, right?

So now my relationship is setup, I try this instead of the above:

`[tableObject addGuestObject:(Person *)editedObject];`

So from the fetch request that I filled my picker view with I work out the selected table and get that object, `tableObject`. Then as the CoreDataBooks example did for me already the `editedObject` has been passed down to this view and is the person in question that we are editing.

So this is where I am liking misunderstanding it. Surely as with the last line of code, we simply take the existing table object (that was selected) and then add the existing guest object to it?

But this gives me this error and crashes:

`'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x145640 <x-coredata://2FAD62C1-382A-4398-A4CA-02B4B41DC9A5/Table/p2>''`

Not entirely sure what to do to remedy this.

Comment: Are you saving the context after adding the person to the table MO?

Comment: Although, I think its crashing before it reaches saving. I put a break point in and it crashes straight after `[tableObject addGuestObject:(Person *)editedObject];`

Comment: Try this just before the addGuestObject line:  `NSLog(@"%@", [editedObject class]);` and make sure that it is actually a Person object as you are expecting.

Comment: Yep the log returns 'Person' which is the entity name.

Comment: Am I even approaching this correctly? Am I doing the right thing to get the existing table and person object and use said method (the one auto created when the classes were made).

Comment: It looks right, try the same with tableObject?

Comment: returns 'Table' just as it should. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the 'could not fulfil fault' means that the object was deleted out from the persistent store yet you still have a reference to the object. That could happen for a number of reasons (persistent store changed, object was deleted by another thread, object was owned by another object with a relationship which had cascade and *it* was deleted). Think we need a bit more info about the relationships from it.

Comment: Turns out it was that I was using the wrong managed object context, use the right one, no problem.